# Maven Pac Proxy Settings.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy, pac

How to configure a Maven proxy [`.PAC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file?
How could I proceed in this case?
I tried it in all conceivable ways, but I could not find a working solution.